# memsql data inflation during recovery

Tags: singlestore

During leaf recovery, data from our databases is inflated almost 50x the original size. If we run "show databases extended;" on each leaf, we can watch the size go from ~40Mb to ~2000Mb for each partition of the database (only during recovery). After recovery it returns to the original size.

We were hosting an 80Gb database, but memsql was unable to recover due to the huge amount of memory required. We had to remove this database in order for memsql to work again.

Is there a way to stop data inflation from crashing the recovery process? It seems like memsql should be able to host 80Gb.

We have one aggregator and 5 leaves, each with ~30Gb Memory and ~400Gb Disks.

Edit:
After upgrading to version 5.0.8 this problem dissappeared

Comment: Out of curiosity, what kind of workload was running on the cluster before the leafs were restarted? Was it heavy with updates and/or deletes? Or mostly inserts and selects?

Comment: mostly inserts and selects. the issue occurs every time with every leaf when we host 80Gb, even with no workload in between restarts. It occurs about half the time with 15Gb we are hosting now.

Answer (score 0):

You could try snapshotting the database (http://docs.memsql.com/docs/snapshot-database). This is likely to help if there is a significant amount of data being updated/deleted.

Comment: FYI part of the default upgrade process is snapshotting all databases, which is likely why the problem disappeared after your upgrade.